# Hall's Marriage Theorem When the Set of Men Has Singular Cardinality $\kappa$ and Each Man Knows at Most $\kappa$ Women

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

Let $\cal F=(A_i)_{i\in\kappa} $ be a family of sets indexed by a set $\kappa$.  A $transversal$ is a one-to-one function $f$ from $\kappa$ to $\bigcup_{i\in\kappa} A_i$ such that for all $i\in\kappa$, $f(i)\in A_i$.

Assume that $\kappa$ is a singular cardinal. Fix $\lambda\le\kappa$ and assume that for every $i\in\kappa$, $|A_i|\le\lambda$. Assume further that, for every subset $J\subset\kappa$ such that $|J|<\kappa$, the subfamily $(A_i)_{i\in J}$ has a transversal.

Theorem 6.4 of Aharoni, Nash-Williams, and Shelah, "A General Criterion for the Existence of Transversals," Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society $\bf 47$ (1983), 43-68 implies that if $\lambda<\kappa$, then $\cal F$ has a transversal.

What if $\lambda=\kappa$?

Note: I am not simply asking for a counterexample (e.g., every man knows one woman except for one man who knows all the women, which I think is what Aharoni et al. call a $1-obstruction$), but for a useful modification of the result. (I realize this is vague.)

Comment: There is a follow-up article with a somewhat different characterization: https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1112/jlms/s2-29.2.193
What happens when you translate the characterizations from both papers to the case you are interested in?